# JsonResult and ObjectResult do not derive from each other—why?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

folks on my team write stuff like this:

```cs
[HttpPost("do")]
public async Task<ActionResult> DoAsync()
{
    try
    {
        var obj = await this.DoThing();

        return new JsonResult(obj);
    }
    catch (StatusCodeException x)
    {
        return StatusCode(x.StatusCode, new { x.Message, x.StackTrace });
    }
    catch (Exception x)
    {
        return StatusCode(500, x.GenerateMessage(" "));
    }
}
```

This means `JsonResult` or `ObjectResult` can be returned which makes testing kind of complicated. This is because `JsonResult` and `ObjectResult` do *not* derive from each other. Does anyone know why this is the case?

I had to write a little wrapper class for testing to make life a bit easier:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Defines all subclasses of <see cref="ActionResult"/>
/// that have status codes and <see cref="object"/> values.
/// </summary>
public class ObjectValueActionResult
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ObjectValueActionResult"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="result">The result.</param>
    /// <remarks>
    /// The majority of <see cref="IActionResult"/> instances like <see cref="OkObjectResult"/> derive
    /// from <see cref="ObjectResult"/>.
    /// </remarks>
    public ObjectValueActionResult(IActionResult result)
    {
        Assert.NotNull(result);
        switch (result)
        {
            case JsonResult j:
                this.Value = j.Value;
                this.StatusCode = j.StatusCode;
                break;
            case NoContentResult n:
                this.StatusCode = n.StatusCode;
                break;
            case ObjectResult o:
                this.Value = o.Value;
                this.StatusCode = o.StatusCode;
                break;
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException($"The expected {nameof(IAsyncResult)} type is not here.");
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The value.
    /// </value>
    public object Value { get; set; }
    /// <summary>Gets or sets the HTTP status code.</summary>
    public int? StatusCode { get; set; }
}
```

Is there an alternative to this?

Comment: Assuming this is an API, you could consider using `ActionResult<T>` instead which allows you to just `return obj` instead of having to create an actual result object. This probably makes it a bit easier for your team to consistently use the same thing. And it’s easier to test too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JsonResult` is intended to return JSON-formatted data, it returns JSON regardless of what format is requested through Accept header. There is no content negotiation happen when we use JsonResult .

Content negotiation is the process of figuring out what type of data browser requested through its Http request Accept header. For example this is an accept header that request content of type HTML: `Accept: application/xml, */*; q=0.01`, with action results of type JsonResult no content negotiation takes place. Which means server ignores the user requested type and return JSON .

`ObjectResult` is an IActionResult that has content negotiation built in. Normally unless you specify an Accept header, the API will serialize the response as JSON. If you specify for example 'application/xml' it will return XML .

Reference :

http://hamidmosalla.com/2017/03/29/asp-net-core-action-results-explained/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-2.2